# ElasticSearch: filter out results from an array

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an array that's of form:

```
[ { _index: 'people',
    _type: 'items',
    _id: '5450c69d9d3545a816df39d4',
    _score: null,
    _source:
     { _id: '5450c69d9d3545a816df39d4',
       number: '2062',
       bids: [Object] },
  { _index: 'people',
    _type: 'items',
    _id: '5450c69d9d3545a816df396d',
    _score: null,
    _source:
     { _id: '5450c69d9d3545a816df396d',
       number: '2195',
       bids: [Object] }
 ]
```

**Detailed item-**

```
{ _id: '5450c69d9d3545a816df391c',
  number: '2004',
  bids:
   [ { collector: '5450c69a9d3545a816df311d',
       state: 'losing',
       createdAt: '2014-10-30T09:33:36.905Z',
       amount: 10,
       _id: '545205f01fc10e3816cb2073' },
     { collector: '5450c69a9d3545a816df311c',
       amount: 20,
       state: 'winning',
       createdAt: '2014-10-30T09:29:38.561Z',
       _id: '545205f01fc10e3816cb2074' } ]
}
```

I want to apply a filter such that I can filter out the winning and losing bids. I want a query that returns the result of such type,ie, the collector who is winning on this item.

```
{ collector: '5450c69a9d3545a816df311c',
   amount: 20,
   state: 'winning',
   createdAt: '2014-10-30T09:29:38.561Z',
   _id: '545205f01fc10e3816cb2074' } ]
```

**The mapping is :**

```
{
  "bids": {
    "properties": {
      "_id": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "amount": {
        "type": "long"
      },
      "collector": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "createdAt": {
        "type": "date",
        "format": "dateOptionalTime"
      },
      "state": {
        "type": "string"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The query should be like `collector=<id> AND bids.state="winning/losing"`

What would be the actual ElasticSearch query?

Comment: can you post your mapping? the `bids` are mapped as `nested` or `object`?

Comment: `          "bids" : {
            "properties" : {
              "_id" : {
                "type" : "string"
              },
              "amount" : {
                "type" : "long"
              },
              "collector" : {
                "type" : "string"
              },
              "createdAt" : {
                "type" : "date",
                "format" : "dateOptionalTime"
              },
              "state" : {
                "type" : "string"
              }
            }`
The query should be like collector=<id> AND bids.state="winning/losing". Right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand, you want ElasticSearch to return **only the winning bid** in its answer. It's not possible with your current mapping.

If a document has multiple bids, using a filter like this :

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "bids.state": "winning"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

won't return the items which have only bids in state *losing*. However, if there are a mix of *winning* and *losing*, the whole document is returned :

```
{
   ...
   "hits": {
      "total": 1,
      "max_score": 1,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "people",
            "_type": "items",
            "_id": "Gpnvxhf_QtGIcaaAeKBiSA",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "number": 2004,
               "bids": [
                  {
                     "collector": "5450c69a9d3545a816df311c",
                     "state": "winning",
                     "createdAt": "2014-10-30T09:29:38.561Z",
                     "amount": 20
                  },
                  {
                     "collector": "5450c69a9d3545a816df311d",
                     "state": "losing",
                     "createdAt": "2014-10-30T09:33:36.905Z",
                     "amount": 10
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

In order to have only the `bids` object returned, you can use a separate type and set up a **parent-child relationship**.

Here follows an example :

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "items": {
      "properties": {
        "number": {
          "type": "long"
        }
      }
    },
    "bids": {
      "_parent": {
        "type": "items"
      },
      "properties": {
        "_id": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "amount": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "collector": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "createdAt": {
          "type": "date",
          "format": "dateOptionalTime"
        },
        "state": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then, adding some values :

```
POST people/items/1
{
  "number": 2004
}

POST people/bids?parent=1
{
  "collector": "5450c69a9d3545a816df311d",
  "state": "losing",
  "createdAt": "2014-10-30T09:33:36.905Z",
  "amount": 10
}

POST people/bids?parent=1
{
  "collector": "5450c69a9d3545a816df311c",
  "state": "winning",
  "createdAt": "2014-10-30T09:29:38.561Z",
  "amount": 20
}
```

You can finally have the desired result by querying like :

```
POST people/bids/_search
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "state": "winning"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

which outputs :

```
{
   ...
   "hits": {
      "total": 1,
      "max_score": 1,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "people",
            "_type": "bids",
            "_id": "BV22GSsaRh6gHukVxL6tVw",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "collector": "5450c69a9d3545a816df311c",
               "state": "winning",
               "createdAt": "2014-10-30T09:29:38.561Z",
               "amount": 20
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

You can find more information about [relationships](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/relations.html) here, and more specifically about parent-child [here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/parent-child.html).

Be aware that parent-child relationships are a last resort solution as they keep in memory the parent id map.